# Measuring timing over many commands in psql

Tags: psql, timing

The \timing command finds time needed for each individual update/query. But I have a .sql file with 10000 inserts and I want to see how much time it takes. How can I achieve this?

Comment: execute the sql, time it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Unix `time`:

```bash
time psql -q -f script.sql
```